# mail delivered then removed in postfix

Tags: dovecot, postfix

I just installed and configured Postfix/Dovecont + Mysql + PostfixAdmin.
When I try to send email from e.g. gmail.com it's delivered but I cannot see it in mail folder. Seems to be deleted. Here is my maillog.
Can anybody help why ?

```
Sep 27 17:12:53 ND-12053 postfix/smtpd[29098]: connect from mail-yw0-f44.google.com[209.85.213.44]
Sep 27 17:12:53 ND-12053 postfix/trivial-rewrite[29101]: warning: do not list domain mydomain.com in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Sep 27 17:12:53 ND-12053 postfix/smtpd[29098]: 9A8B69E0F9D: client=mail-yw0-f44.google.com[209.85.213.44]
Sep 27 17:12:53 ND-12053 postfix/cleanup[29102]: 9A8B69E0F9D: message-id=<CAOgJ1rEcfNDy2yr7mmj9zTi=0UYOS-DdZYSohR9Bv987MiFVPQ@mail.gmail.com>
Sep 27 17:12:53 ND-12053 postfix/qmgr[27094]: 9A8B69E0F9D: from=<someuser@gmail.com>, size=1482, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 27 17:12:53 ND-12053 postfix/trivial-rewrite[29101]: warning: do not list domain mydomain.com in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Sep 27 17:12:53 ND-12053 postfix/trivial-rewrite[29101]: warning: do not list domain mydomain.com in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Sep 27 17:12:53 ND-12053 postfix/trivial-rewrite[29101]: warning: do not list domain mydomain.com in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Sep 27 17:12:53 ND-12053 postfix/local[29103]: 9A8B69E0F9D: to=<root@mydomain.com>, orig_to=<info@mydomain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.04, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Sep 27 17:12:53 ND-12053 postfix/qmgr[27094]: 9A8B69E0F9D: removed
```

Email folder list:

```
drwx------ 2 postfix postfix 4096 sep 27 16:43 cur
-rw------- 1 postfix postfix  248 sep 27 16:43 dovecot.index.log
-rw------- 1 postfix postfix   48 sep 27 16:47 dovecot.mailbox.log
-rw------- 1 postfix postfix   51 sep 27 16:43 dovecot-uidlist
-rw------- 1 postfix postfix    8 sep 27 16:47 dovecot-uidvalidity
-r--r--r-- 1 postfix postfix    0 sep 27 16:43 dovecot-uidvalidity.4e82357b
drwx------ 2 postfix postfix 4096 sep 27 16:43 new
-rw------- 1 postfix postfix   21 sep 27 16:47 subscriptions
drwx------ 2 postfix postfix 4096 sep 27 16:43 tmp
```

Answer (score 4):

"delivered to maildir". Everything is fine. Look into the maildir and it will be there.

Other (not related in any way!) thing: Read the second line and correct this in your configuration.

Comment: I added email folder list in the question box. Look at the top. Non of those folders contain the message

Comment: @chubbyk So then it is in the `cur` or `new` folder. Dependent on if the mail is new or read.